# Loading spreadsheet template file doesn't retain form button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, spreadsheetgear

I am using SpreadsheetGear 2012 in my application to load, modify then save a new copy of a template workbook.

My code takes invoicing information from a database and formats it for the workbook.  Then the user will print an invoice from the formatted information using a button on the workbook.

I use a template workbook with some formatting already provided to make my life easier.  Included on the original template workbook is a button that runs a VBA macro in the spreadsheet.  The VBA macro loads successfully but the button just disappears in the new workbook.

Some of the steps I have tried to rectify the issue: I've added a new button, changed the VBA macro code from a function to a sub, saved the template file as a macro-enabled spreadsheet (.xlsm) and saved the revised copy as a macro-enabled spreadsheet file.

Has anyone experienced this issue and do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
SpreadsheetGear 2023 / V9 is now available and supports reading and writing Form Controls using the Open XML (.xlsx / .xlsm) file formats.  Other than upgrading to this version, no other action should need to be taken other than opening or saving your files with Form Controls and having these objects now be persisted.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you are using the Open XML file formats (XLSX/XLSM), then this is a known limitation:

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear_2012_Limitations.html

In short, SpreadsheetGear 2012 does not support reading/writing Form Controls (like buttons), as well as Cell Comments, when working with the Open XML file formats.  So your button is getting dropped when the file is initially read into SpreadsheetGear.

If you want to preserve these objects through SpreadsheetGear, you will need to use the XLS ([FileFormat](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.html).Excel8) file format, which does support them.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  You were right, I was using the Open XML formats.  Ultimately, this did not solve the issue.  It seems to be an issue with Microsoft Excel itself - when I recreated the button and reassigned the macro code it worked.  I am accepting your answer because it did lead me in the right direction for the solution.